# What does "runner job" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Could you, please, help me to understand, what can be meant by "runner job"?

According to Google and dictionaries, there can be many different "runners"; context does not help at all. Is it some kind of temporary job?
Action goes in UK, London.

> “So? Ibiza, then? Ian will give me the time off, and
> I’ve got a month until my next **runner job**. Whoop,
> whoop! Ibiza, here we come.” The bed squeaks in
> protest as Daisy bounces up and down.
>
> She’s got Ian, her boss, wrapped around her little finger. He lets
> her work in The King’s Arms whenever she’s in between **runner jobs**, so
> he won’t bat an eyelid if she suddenly announces she’s off on holiday
> for three weeks.

C.L. Taylor "The Lie"

Comment: OP says "context does not help at all" but the context can tell you what Daisy's main job is.

Comment: There is no information about Daisy's main job. She "works in The King’s Arms whenever she’s in between runner jobs," Thats all I know.

Comment: If you read the book, I expect there is. I've just been reading a [synopsis](https://thebookwormsfantasy.com/2016/07/24/book-review-the-lie-by-c-l-taylor/) and perhaps "runner" means "drug runner" although that hasn't been specifically mentioned.

Comment: I finished the book.

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing? *I particularly enjoyed reading about Emma and Daisy’s relationship. The girls appear to be in competition with each other and this is further heightened when they reach Nepal ... Each character is explored in great detail, leaving me with the feeling that I personally knew all of the girls and all their ins and outs.* A runner could be: drug runner, courier, messenger. Why would we know her job?

Comment: Third definition in Cambridge Dictionary: "a person who works for someone by taking messages, collecting money, etc."

Comment: I'd have thought the most common place for a runner was at a TV or radio station — you might be contracted to work on one programme (rather than having a full time job there), when it finishes, you have to look for a new job. Runners take messages, collect people from dressing rooms, go and get lunch for people who can't leave etc https://nationalcareers.service.gov.uk/job-profiles/tv-or-film-production-runner (I never thought of drug runner as being an option!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/runner):

> Runner
> a person who works for someone by taking messages, collecting money, etc.

The job title 'runner' is used in offices and also on film sets for general assistants who go and get coffees, food etc for VIPs. The work tends to be of a casual nature which fits with the description in your book that they are 'between' such jobs.

Comment: Suppose, film set assistant fits here perfectly!

Comment: @KristinaLukosevice That's the context where I've heard it the most. Music venues also have runners to go and get things that performers ask for, coffee, drinks etc. Certain celebrities often make last-minute demands and runners are there to keep them happy.